# Query optimization that takes about a minute to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

There is a simple table that stores IIS log.

Table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_iisLog](
    [cdate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ctime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [serverip] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [uri] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [port] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [clientip] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [useragent] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note that I have added these three indexes on the following fields:

- `username`
- `clientip`
- Combination of (`cdate` and `ctime`)

To the table, the following query takes about 50 - 60 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    username Usename,

    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(useragent, PATINDEX('%SIG:+%',useragent) + 5, 36))
        FROM tbl_iislog AS SoftwareSignatureCountTempTable
        WHERE (PATINDEX('%SIG:+%',useragent) > 0)
            AND SoftwareSignatureCountTempTable.username = MainTBL.username
    ) AS SoftwareSignatureCount

    ,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
        LEFT(useragent, IIF((PATINDEX('%VDB%',useragent) -1) > 0, PATINDEX('%VDB%',useragent) -1, 0))
        +
        RIGHT(useragent, IIF((PATINDEX('%BPC%',useragent) -1) > 0, PATINDEX('%BPC%',useragent) -1, 0))
        )
        FROM TBL_iislog UseragentTempTable
        WHERE UseragentTempTable.username = MainTBL.username
    ) AS UserAgentCount

    ,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clientip)
        FROM tbl_iislog AS IPTempTable
        WHERE IPTempTable.username = MainTBL.username
    ) AS IPCount

    ,
    (SELECT COUNT(clientip)
        FROM tbl_iislog ConnectionsTempTable
        WHERE ConnectionsTempTable.uri = '/version_checker.ver'
        AND ConnectionsTempTable.username = MainTBL.username
    ) AS Connections

    FROM TBL_iisLog AS MainTBL
    WHERE (username LIKE 'softgsg-%') OR (username LIKE 'sg-%')
    GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(clientip) > 0
    ORDER BY SoftwareSignatureCount DESC, Connections DESC
```

I would thank any advise helping me to optimize my query.

Comment: can you post the execution plans?

Comment: I think you could simplify this greatly.  It looks like all of your counts are coming from the same table (`TBL_iislog`), but you're spinning through it multiple times.  Try and replace all those funky sub-queries with case statements so you're only hitting the table once.

Comment: I am taking a look at what can be done....did you create separate indexes for clientip and username, and are they non-clustered indexes? would you be able to provide a script of the indexes you created please?

Answer (score 2):

First, others commented and true... the query was a mess, and having so many field-level select statements can KILL performance as each query is executed for EVERY RECORD, EVERY COLUMN you are running against.  They were all based on whatever the current user was, just happened to be IIF() of certain criteria.  I've simplified and it might need a LITTLE bit of adjustment, but SHOULD SIGNIFICANTLY help you out.

First, your count of specific clientIP as basis of HAVING clause doesn't really matter that column, but would be best by just * indicating the record existed regardless of a specific column.  Also, in this same query level, by doing a SUM( IIF() ) can handle your Version Checker "Connections" count.

FOR your signature entries I am doing this two-fold from the same run.  First, I am getting a flag via MAX( IIF() ) to see if ANY of the records do NOT have the '%SIG:+%' reference, then also getting a COUNT( distinct OF that signature finding ).  This way, the COUNT
less any non-signatures (which would all be treated as blank space ' ' so deduct a maximum of 1 entry no matter how many Non "SIG" entries will give the ACTUAL final count.

I also don't know why you have a HAVING COUNT of IPs > 0...   From an IIS log file, everything should have a client IP, so I believe this is irrelevant and thus removed.

I also think I severely simplified your user agent field.  If it doesn't find the '%VDB%' or "%BPC%' entries, just use empty string, otherwise get the substring context of each.

So, now with a single pass through the table with all aggregations done ONCE through should help.  Now, indexes.  Since you are using a LIKE in your where clause, but good thing is you are not liking a leading '%' which would otherwise indicate your are looking for the string "softgsg-" or "sg-" ANYwhere in the string, you are looking for it in the LEADING portion of the string WHICH CAN be optimized by an index.

That being said, I would have a compound index on the table of

( username, clientip )

Since your columns are dealing with 255 and even MAX column width text, I don't want to kill the index just to have it a "covering" index.

```
select
      PQ.*
   from 
      ( SELECT
              L.username,
              COUNT(*) TotalRecs,
              COUNT(DISTINCT clientip) DistinctIPs,
              SUM( IIF( L.uri = '/version_checker.ver', 1, 0 )) as Connections,
              MAX( IIF( PATINDEX('%SIG:+%', L.useragent) = 0, 1, 0 )) as NonSigEntries,
              COUNT( DISTINCT IIF( PATINDEX('%SIG:+%', L.useragent) = 0, ' ',
                                   SUBSTRING( L.useragent, PATINDEX('%SIG:+%', L.useragent) + 5, 36))) SoftwareSignatureCount,
              COUNT( DISTINCT 
                        IIF(PATINDEX('%VDB%', L.useragent) = 0, '', LEFT( L.useragent, PATINDEX('%VDB%', L.useragent) -1))
                      + IIF(PATINDEX('%BPC%', L.useragent) = 0, '', RIGHT( L.useragent, PATINDEX('%BPC%', L.useragent) -1))
                    ) AS UserAgentCount
           FROM 
              tbl_iislog L
           WHERE 
                 L.username LIKE 'softgsg-%'
              OR L.username LIKE 'sg-%'
           GROUP BY
              L.username ) PQ
   ORDER BY
      PQ.SoftwareSignatureCount - PQ.NonSigEntries DESC,
      PQ.Connections DESC
```

The query runs as I tested against an empty table structure as provided by your query.  Due to the order by, I pre-wrapped the query (alias PQ for PreQuery), so I would have the final values of the software signature count and non-signature entries flag, then connections so I didn't have to re-copy the same COUNT( complex statements ) into both the fields list AND order by... Some engines allow you to use the column result name alias vs the entire expression.